# SQL: How do I separate Union all into separate columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

new user. So I'm making an SQL database project themed around an escape room/restaurant and I have two separate tables, one called ingredients and another called assets.
Below is an example of the Ingredients Table

```
| ingredients_id | ingredients_name | ingredients_cost | ingredient_stock | ingredient_availability
| 1              | Beef Burger      | 1.99             | 12               | 1 
| 2              | Cheese           | 1.99             | 0                | 0
| 3              | Bacon            | 1.99             | 43               | 1
```

and this is an example of the assets table

```
| asset_id | asset_name | asset_status | asset_availability
| 1        | escape_1   | Clean        | 1          
| 2        | escape_2   | Clean        | 1
| 3        | escape_3   | Clean        | 1
```

What I'm trying to do is make a table that combines the both of them called Storage (Already have the table through primary/foreign key), here's what I want it to appear as:

```
| Name        | Stock (Ingredients Only) | Availability
| escape_1    | NULL                     | TRUE
| escape_2    | NULL                     | TRUE
| escape_3    | NULL                     | TRUE
| Beef Burger | 12                       | TRUE
| Cheese      | 0                        | FALSE
| Bacon       | 43                       | TRUE
```

Here's my SQL code so far:

```
SELECT asset_name AS "Name" FROM escaperoom_assets 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ingredients_name FROM ingredients
```

I'm able to put the ingredient and asset names into one list but I can't make a separate column for the others. Essentially I want it so that it'll display a list of all the assets and ingredients in one column, check how much is in stock for the other (only for the ingredients table), and if they are available or not (identified as True/False or 0 or 1).

Comment: Okay for some reason the table format messed up completely nor can i figure out  how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Just add the columns you want in each subquery:

```
SELECT asset_name AS Name, NULL as stock, asset_availabilty as availability
FROM escaperoom_assets 
UNION ALL 
SELECT ingredients_name, ingredient_stock, ingredient_availability
FROM ingredients;
```

I'm not sure why you want to convert 0/1 to true/false.  The numbers seem fine, but you can use conditional logic to convert them to strings if you want.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I'll do some quick changes so I can replace the 1 and 0 as True/False and rename the "stock" and "asset_availability" with proper names.

Comment: Anyways in regards to the True/False thing, I'm doing that so it looks a bit more professional as it makes somewhat more sense to display the information as True or False instead of a 0/1.

Comment: @FoxyWoxy0w0 . . . Often formatting such values is done at the API level, but you can easily change the third argument to a `case` expression:  `(case when asset_availability then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE end)`.